# not able to ping filenet content engine ever after successful deployment of ear

Tags: ibm-was, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I have added CE application to WAS server but not able to ping it. 
WAS server containing Filenet Application is at port number 9063 and i am pinging content engine url at default 9080 port. Is this a problem?. How can I find out on which port content engine is running.

Answer (score 0):

What are you mean - ping application?

Are you sure that you Content Engine application is started? You should start it after deploy.

User health-url to check avalibility of CE.
Look chapter ["Verifying the Content Platform Engine server status"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.common.admin.doc/startup_shutdown/verify_cpe_status.htm?lang=en) from documentation